# Why Clojure's reverse function returns a non-lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure, lisp, lazy-evaluation

Why the designers of Clojure's reverse function decided that the returned sequence isn't a lazy one?
Clojure embraces lazy sequences usually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surely it's because by definition, in order to reverse a sequence, you have to know what's at the other end in order to return what will become the first item in the reversed collection.

Hence, the sequence must be finite, and you'd have to evaluate it in order to use what lies at it's end.

Addendum:

Reverse doesn't make sense as an infinite sequence, (although it's fair to say that infinite sequences are not always a prerequisite for laziness).

If you are about to reverse a collection, then you already have it loaded in memory; it doesn't need to be calculated.

Comment: What? You mean your computers only ever run forwards in time?! Ridiculous! (;-))

Comment: I got your point but maybe I'm missing something. Yes the sequence should has an end in order to be reverse-able, but why reverse function returns a non-lazy result?

Comment: @Chiron But have already read all of the end, there is no sense to delay.

Comment: From the Joy of Clojure: "The primary advantage of laziness in Clojure is that it prevents the full realization of interim results during a calculation" … "laziness guarantees that sequences won’t be fully realized in memory at any given step". In the case of a reversal, we have no interim results. It's all done in one move with a reduce & conj.

Comment: >>> e.g. `(reduce conj () '(1 2 3))` => `(3 2 1)`

Comment: If you want on it, (lazy-seq *1)

Answer (score 9):

`rseq` returns a seq that traverse a collection in reverse order. It only works on *reversible* collections such as vector, sorted-set and sorted-map.

`reverse` will reverse any finite seq but does so at the cost of going through all the items and perpending them to a list. It is implemented as `(reduce conj () coll)`. This is obviously non-lazy.

Comment: This explains "why" in terms of how it's implemented. It doesn't answer why this implementation is chosen, which I think is the real question.

Comment: @ivant This implementation is chosen for its efficiency. You could build a lazy version of reverse which traverses the input seq numerous times up to the [(count-1)th, (count-2)th, (count-3)th, …] item as a lazy seq is consumed. But building a list in one go and returning it makes more sense. For collections that are reversible of course you should use rseq.

Answer (score 2):

Further to [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205233/1562315):

The `reverse` function reduces its sequence argument, element by element. If we can make `reverse` truly lazy, we can do the same with other reductions. So let's write a lazy version of `reduce`:

```
(defn lazy-reduce [f init coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (if (seq coll)
     (lazy-reduce f (f init (first coll)) (rest coll))
     init)))
```

This only works on sequences, by the way.

But it works:

```
(lazy-reduce conj () (range 5))
; (4 3 2 1 0)
```

*If we never touch the result*, nothing is computed. We win. But *as soon as we touch the first element*, the whole sequence is realized, unravelling like knitting with a dropped stitch.

Comment: btw Jeff Terrell has an interesting blog post [Lazy reduce in Clojure](https://jeffterrell.tech/posts/2015-02-24-lazy-reduce-in-clojure/).